# For Next Loop Failing: Match values in Col A (Sheet 1) to Col A (Sheet 2) and then Match columns

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, matrix

I've tried to use code found in another workbook to fit my situation but when run, it returns no values. Would appreciate any insight on how to salvage this.

**GOAL: To build a matrix that shows each measure and mark an "X" for the dimensions it uses.**

Col A in the MATRIX Sheet has a list of measures.
The subsequent columns are (Col B, C, etc.) are all the Dimensions.

Col A in the FTD Sheet are also a list of measures, but they repeat.
Col B is a list of corresponding dimensions to each measure. (same as column names in MATRIX sheet)

The goal is to match the measures in Col A, MATRIX sheet to > Col A, FTD Sheet. If found in the FTD sheet, it should check the corresponding dimension to that measure, find it within the columns on the MATRIX sheet  and mark an "X" under the corresponding column.

Note: The dimensions in both sheets are the same type/format, etc. (they are both derived from the same source)

```
Matrix Sheet:

COL A          DIMENSION A(Cost)      DIMENSION B(Hours Worked)    Hours Forecast  Accounts Receivable   Location 
Measure 1          x                            x                              x 
Measure 2          x                                                           x 
Measure 3                                       x
Measure 4          x                                                           x                             x
```

```
FTD Sheet:


COL A         COL B
Measure 1     DIMENSION A(Cost) 
Measure 1     Hours Worked
Measure 1     Hours Forecast 
Measure 2     Accounts Receivable
Measure 2     Location
Measure 3     Location
```

Code below:

```
Public Sub ltdsol()


Set sht = Worksheets("Matrix")
Set sht2 = Worksheets("FTD")
MATRIXLastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
FTDLastrow = sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To MATRIXLastRow
    ' Find the row with a matching Case ID/Client Name
    For k = 2 To FTDLastrow
        If sht.Cells(k, 1).Value = sht2.Cells(i, 1).Value Then _
            Exit For
    Next

    q = 3 ' Starting column for Questions, look for a matching question/header (or blank)
    Do Until sht2.Cells(1, q).Value = sht.Cells(i, 3).Value Or sht2.Cells(1, q).Value = vbNullString
        q = q + 1
    Loop


    ' Write the Response
    sht2.Cells(k, q).Value = "X"
Next

End Sub
```

Would appreciate any assistance. Thank you.

Comment: This can be done with a simple formula: `=IF(COUNTIFS(FTD!$A:$A,$A2,FTD!$B:$B,B$1),"X","")`

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I don't think this accounts for the fact that corresponding dimensions are column headings going from Col C to CF.

Comment: @Scott Craner's suggestion should work. The problem isn't in the solution but in the test. I suspect that your column captions like "Dimension A" aren't true representatives of the real data. If "Dimension A" would be a value like 3.141592613 Scott's solution would fail to find 3.1416 in the FTD file. The same would be true if one of the values were a text string of the identical number. The advantages of the simplicity of Scott's suggestion should induce you to afford it a proper test. Alternatively, prepare for any other solution also to fail for the same reason.

Comment: Hi, that made a lot of sense - thank you for your response. I've edited the post with actual dimension examples instead of what I had before. I hope this helps clarify this better?

Comment: As per @Variatus comment, nothing is going to work unless you have the same values on both sheets `DIMENSION A(Cost)` <> `Dimension A(Cost)`.  Make sure that they are exactly the same, same case and no extra spaces at the end.

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner - I spent sometime re-applying your formula and this works. Thank you for this. I have upvoted your response. Much appreciated and thanks to the community for helping me re-assess my question and the test provided.

Would you be able to repost your comment as the solution so I can upvote and mark as the best response?

Comment: As you are not asking for a formula in your question, My formula would be deemed off topic and open for down votes.  I will just leave it as a comment.  I am glad it helped.

Comment: You can do an index/match2x here. I'm assuming your tables start at cell A1.
`=index([your source table], match(A2, [source table col A],0), Match(B2, [source table row 1], 0))` This will basically use your key in A2 and B2 to find the intersect in the other table and pull it into your sheet, no VBA required.

Comment: @MarkS.Thanks for this. I'll try this as well.